# bitNot = (sbyte)(~bitNot) VS. myInt = Int32.Parse(myInput);

Tags: c#

```
bitNot = (sbyte)(~bitNot)
```

VS.

```
myInt = Int32.Parse(myInput);
```

Hello, I'm a bit confused on the above two statements... it seems like both statements are trying to convert, but why is the syntax bitNot = (sbyte)(~bitNot) for the first statement?
why can't we use bitNot = sbyte.Parse(~bitNot) like the syntax we have on the second statement? Thanks

Comment: The first statement inverts all the bits of a sbyte, the other parses a string into an integer. What's the connection between these 2 statements you show ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first statement takes `bitNot`, which is presumably some form of integer, inverts all the bits, cast it into an `sbyte`, and stores the result back in `bitNot`

The second statement takes `myInput`, which is most likely a string of some sort, parses it from a human-readable form into an `Int32` type, and stores that in `myInt`.

The major difference is the types you are operating on; you only need `Parse` if you are dealing with strings. In first statement, a cast operation is being done instead; this usually means converting from a 32-bit integer to a 8-bit integer, for example. It is a very different kind of operation.